# Visual studio "an unknown object" while trying to print

Tags: printing, visual-studio-2019

When I try to print with Visual Studio I get a message that says "An object that does not derive from System.Exception has been wrapped in a RuntimeWrappedException".

I'm using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 and did an update today. Note that this has nothing to do with update because it has been happening a long time.

When I try to search for this term all I get is information that is relevant to writing an application.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Do you mean literal printing as in paper? What type of printer are you trying to use and at what point in the process exactly does the error message pop up?

Comment: Yes, to paper. It happens with my HP 1022n and my HP 8710. It never makes it to the choice of printers.

Comment: Try setting a different printer as the default printer. Maybe even a virtual printer like the XPS or PDF printer.